# Loop through a worksheet and insert a row with layout when value is true

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I have a code that does a loop through a worksheets, if there is a value 2 inside a cell in column S, then I want to insert a row with a specific layout. I have the code, but it takes ages to complete. I've tried replacing .select function, but because I need a specific layout, I don't know how to avoid this.

```
LastRowMatchC = Worksheets("Compliance").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim rngc As Range, rc As Long

Set rngc = Range("S8:S" & LastRowMatchC)

For rc = rngc.Count To 1 Step -1
    If rngc(rc).Value = 2 Then
        rngc(rc + 1).EntireRow.Insert
        rngc(rc + 1).EntireRow.Select

    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
        .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone

    End If
Next rch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Always use [Option Explicit](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html) and declare your variables as close as possible to their first use.
- Fully [qualify your worksheet references](https://www.spreadsheetsmadeeasy.com/7-common-vba-mistakes-to-avoid/) (see #5)

When calculating your `LastRowMatchC`, always make sure to fully qualify ALL worksheet references like this

```
Worksheets("Compliance").Cells(Worksheets("Compliance").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

or

```
With Worksheets("Compliance")
    LastRowMatchC = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

(Notice the dot in front of the `Rows`) Otherwise, the the `Rows.Count` is looking at the currently active worksheet and not the one you intended.

- Use `EnableEvents` and `ScreenUpdating` when you're making changes directly on the worksheet.

You can turn off events and screen updating before and after your loop to give a big speed boost to the reformatting:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For rc = rngc.Count To 1 Step -1
    '--- do your thing here
Next rc

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

(More on this in the next comment)

- [Avoid using `Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/4717755) and try to define any constant "magic values" in an expression. No one knows why you're looking for the value "2" here (and you may not remember a year from now). So replace the `MAGIC_VALUE` name with something meaningful to your application.

A partial example using your code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsertRows()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With Worksheets("Compliance")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Dim rngc As Range
    Set rngc = Worksheets("Compliance").Range("S8:S" & lastRow)

    AppPerformance SetTo:=False

    Const MAGIC_VALUE As Long = 2

    Dim rc As Long
    For rc = rngc.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If rngc(rc).Value = MAGIC_VALUE Then
            rngc(rc + 1).EntireRow.Insert
            Dim newRow As Range
            Set newRow = rngc(rc + 1).EntireRow
            With newRow
                With .Interior
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
                    .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
                    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                End With
                .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
                .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
                With .Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .ColorIndex = 0
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .Weight = xlThin
                End With
                '--- keep going with formatting ...
            End With
        End If
    Next rc

    AppPerformance SetTo:=True

End Sub

Private Sub AppPerformance(ByVal SetTo As Boolean)
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = SetTo
        .ScreenUpdating = SetTo
    End With
End Sub
```